# How to specify approximate margins in Galen Framework?

Tags: layout, automated-tests, approximate, pixel-perfect, galen

I am using galen framework in a responsive designed website. And I need to check the elements by not giving fixed pixel amounts but percentages. For example I have to check one element to be on the left by approximately 10%. How can I say it in galen? I know how to say "approximately 10% width", but I have nothing to do woth the width and height here.
I need to say approximately %10 left of screen.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use ranges for that, see [here](http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-spec-language-guide/#Ranges):

```
width 10 % of screen/width
```

or

```
inside screen ~10 % left
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is to say: approximately 30 px from left. I don't care about the width.